Error in Jetpack compose when injecting viewModel in Main Activity
I am getting below exception while running the app.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.nishant.comicslibrary, PID: 29957
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:89)
at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:170)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:69)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)

This is my MainActivity
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    //private val lvm by viewModels<LibraryApiViewModel>()

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    private val lvm: LibraryApiViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ComicsLibraryTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController()
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    CharactersScaffold(navController = navController, lvm = lvm)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CharactersScaffold(navController: NavHostController, lvm: LibraryApiViewModel) {
    //val ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
        //scaffoldState = ScaffoldState,
        bottomBar = { CharacterBottomNav(navController = navController)}
    ) { paddingValues ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Destination.Library.route,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            composable(Destination.Library.route) {
                LibraryScreen(navController, lvm, paddingValues)
            }
            composable(Destination.Collection.route) {
                CollectionScreen()
            }
            composable(Destination.CharacterDetail.route) {navBackStackEntery ->

            }
        }
    }
}

ViewModel class
@HiltViewModel
class LibraryApiViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: MarvelApiRepo
): ViewModel() {
 // View model code
}

My lib.version.toml file
[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.1"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
hilt = "2.51.1"
navVersion = "2.7.7"
coilVersion = "2.1.0"
lifecycleVersion = "2.8.1"
retrofitVersion = "2.11.0"
roomVersion = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
google-dagger-hilt = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
google-dagger-hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
androidx-navigation = {group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose", version.ref = "navVersion"}
io-coil = {group = "io.coil-kt", name = "coil-compose", version.ref = "coilVersion"}
androidx-viewmodel-compose = {group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleVersion"}
com-squareup-retrofit = {group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", name = "retrofit", version.ref = "retrofitVersion"}
com-squareup-retrofit-converter-gson = {group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", name = "converter-gson", version.ref = "retrofitVersion"}
androidx-room = {group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "roomVersion"}
androidx-room-compiler = {group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "roomVersion"}
androidx-room-ktx = {group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "roomVersion"}

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
androidx-room = {id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "roomVersion"}

My project level build.gradle file
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false

}

My app level build.gradle file
import java.util.Properties
import java.io.FileInputStream

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt)
}

val apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
val apikeyProperties = Properties()
apikeyProperties.load(FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))

android {
    namespace = "com.nishant.comicslibrary"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.nishant.comicslibrary"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        buildConfigField("String", "MARVEL_KEY", apikeyProperties.getProperty("MARVEL_KEY"))
        buildConfigField("String", "MARVEL_SECRET", apikeyProperties.getProperty("MARVEL_SECRET"))
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    room {
        schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)

    //hilt
    implementation(libs.google.dagger.hilt)
    kapt(libs.google.dagger.hilt.compiler)

    //navigation
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation)

    //coil
    implementation(libs.io.coil)

    //viewmodel compose
    implementation(libs.androidx.viewmodel.compose)

    //Retrofit
    implementation(libs.com.squareup.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.com.squareup.retrofit.converter.gson)

    //room
    implementation(libs.androidx.room)
    kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}


I cannot reproduce the problem. Please create a new project and copy everything from this question into it and run it. It will work as expected, so now start copying the remaining code from your original project step by step over until it fails. This way you can narrow down where the actual error is.

By seeing your code, which I think the part you missed is, you didn't annotated your MainActivity with @AndroidEntryPoint annotation for hilt to work. For that reason, hilt is unable to inject instance of your LibraryApiViewModel in MainActivity thus throwing error.

Sorry, it was aded but not showing. I have edited the post, now you can see it
